# How can I reliably login by username in hook_form_user_login_form_alter for SSO?

Tags: 8, users

I'm integrating SSO for one of my Drupal 8 websites.
We have on-premise SSO and getting user details and respective user roles from SSO response.

When I try below code, sometimes it works. Sometimes it is not working, as I couldn't navigate to pages after login.

**Response from SSO:**

- user name, email, roles (Approved roles for this user).

After login, I am able to see admin menu but the ***login form is still displayed*** which should not be there for authenticated users.

**Main issues:**

- Not able to navigate to pages as it redirects with anonymous session.
- The user login form still displays even though I logged in as admin.

```
// Used below code in "hook_form_user_login_form_alter" 
$user = user_load_by_name($username);
user_login_finalize($user); 

$front_page = Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString(); 
$response = new RedirectResponse($front_page); 
$response->send();
```

Comment: An implementation of `hook_form_alter()` should not redirect users in that way. Furthermore, that code would not work.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thank you very much for your response. Could you please explain me how do I achieve it? I'm thinking to do it by two choices
1) Event API - Anonymous user visit the page, trigger the event and start doing this implementation
2) Or Create custom route and do all those stuff

Really appreciate your valuable suggestion :)